# How to wrap the contents of all datatype but not only string inside " " using `json2csv` library in node js?

Tags: node.js, json, csv, json2csv

**[json2csv](https://juanjodiaz.github.io/json2csv/#/) only wrapped up the string types inside double quotes (" "). But I want all the contents of different datatype like numbers, boolean, null etc, to be wrapped up in (" ") too.**

**Below is my piece of code:**

```
function generateCSV(jsonData: any[], fileName: string): void {
  const opts = {
    defaultValue: "",
    quotes: '"',
  };
  const parser = new Parser(opts);
  const csvData = parser.parse(jsonData);
  console.log(csvData);

  fs.writeFile(fileName, csvData, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error saving CSV:", err);
    } else {
      console.log("CSV saved successfully.");
      parentPort?.postMessage("success");
    }
  });
```

**My input data is like this:**

```
[
    {
      name: "Alice",
      age: 28,
      department: "HR",
      contact: "hell",
      phone: "123-456-7890",
      email: "alice@example.com",
    },
    {
      name: "Bob",
      age: 32,
      department: "Engineering",
      contact: false,
      email: "bob@example.com",
      phone: "987-654-3210",
    },
    {
      name: "Charlie",
      age: null,
      phone: 9876543210,
      department: "Marketing",
    },
];
```

**And my output is like this:**

```
"name","age","department","contact","phone","email"
"Alice",28,"HR","hell","123-456-7890","alice@example.com"
"Bob",32,"Engineering",false,"987-654-3210","bob@example.com"
"Charlie",,"Marketing","",9876543210,""
```

**The output I expect or want it to be wrapped up all elements:**

```
"name","age","department","contact","phone","email"
"Alice","28","HR","hell","123-456-7890","alice@example.com"
"Bob","32","Engineering","false","987-654-3210","bob@example.com"
"Charlie","","Marketing","","9876543210",""
```

Well, I tried other alternative libraries like papaparse and json-2-doc too. But they didn't work as expected too.

I also tried making customFormatter as well but it didn't work too. You can help me by making proper customFormatter too.

Comment: "*I also tried making customFormatter as well*" well maybe you could show how you tried, and someone could point out the issue with that, because it should be possible with custom formatters

Answer (score 0):

Use [transforms](https://juanjodiaz.github.io/json2csv/#/advanced-options/transforms), and pass in your function, which will then turn all values into a string:

Try this:

```
// turn all values into a string
function myTransformer(item) {
    
    for (const p in item) {
        item[p] = item[p] !== null ? String(item[p]) : '';
    }
    return item;
}

const opts = {
    defaultValue: "",
    quotes: '"',
    transforms: [
        myTransformer
    ]

};
```

Comment: Well, your code didn't actually help but I improvised and a made my own custom function to transform all the data to strings. 

Anyway, thank you very much for your idea to convert all data to strings first.

Comment: what do you mean, how it didn't help, which part, because it's producing exact output as you expected